# Project-specific SBT JVM options

Tags: sbt

For a project, I need to start *SBT* with specific *JVM* options (`-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and a number of memory/gc options) - but I don't necessarily want to apply those same options to every SBT project I have.

I've seen references (in *[sbt-extras](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras)*) to the `.sbtopts` (project-specific *SBT* command line options) and `.jvmopts` (project-specific *SBT JVM* options) files that are supposed to support this, if found in the root directory of an *SBT* project, but the standard *Windows* version of *SBT* (I'm using version **0.13.1**) seems to ignore them.

(The *sbt-extras* approach appeals to me because, assuming that `.sbtopts` and `.jvmopts` are tracked in version control, there is zero *SBT* configuration required for people wishing to build the project.)

Is there a current mechanism to specify project-specific *SBT* options that works cross platform?

**UPDATE**: Since I originally raised this question, `.sbtopts` and `.jvmopts` are now part of the standard *Linux* version of *SBT*, and *sbt-extras* is no longer required. However, the *Windows* version only supports `.jvmopts` and does not recognize `.sbtopts`.

Comment: Placing options in `.jvmopts` and `.sbtopts` is an additional feature provided by sbt-extras, it is *not* supported by SBT itself. You should try running sbt-extras using cygwin.

Comment: That's a good point, @gourlaysama, but I guess my reservation would be that I don't want to have to force people using the project to install cygwin on Windows just to simplify using sbt. It seems like a lot more effort than simply asking them to set the required options in the `sbt\conf\sbtopts` and `sbt\conf\sbtconfig.txt` files (which would, admittedly, affect all their projects).

Comment: Correction: reading `.sbtopts` (in the current directory) is supported by sbt. It is only `.jvmopts` that is added by sbt-extras. But `.sbtopts` is enough: you can, for example, add `-J-Xmx1G` so `.sbtopts` instead of adding `-Xmx1G` to `.jvmopts`. But you are right, the `sbt.bat` script doesn't read it on Windows...

Comment: I seem to find no references to `.sbtopts` in the sources of SBT. I don't think it's supported and may only be what shell scripts offer.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I meant that the standard bash runner of sbt (here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/blob/master/src/universal/bin/sbt ) does read the content of `.sbtopts`, but sadly the Windows runner doesn't. Even though it is a shell script, it is definitely packaged with SBT (0.13) itself.

Comment: It begs a pull request then ;-)

Comment: BTW, thanks for posting the reference to the project. I didn't know about it yet appears very useful to know (and ultimately contribute to).

Comment: Correction to @gourlaysama's correction: BOTH `.sbtopts` & `.jvmopts` are [supported since 1.3.14 (anno 2016)](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/commit/45badebcee9f33f8792144d2bf6048c2d1313347) and mentioned in the updated question. I didn't read the update before writing this comment, so if you are reading this, you too have probably _not_ read the update! 

Comment: @conny Thanks for pointing that out. Just one minor correction, the [commit](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/commit/b5fd78f74bf1dc38bbc4203067dabb0f54dd5ea7) introducing `.sbtopts` support in the _Windows_ version was made 1 year ago (10/9/2019), and was released some time later, not in 2016.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a recognized limitation with the current version of *SBT* (v1.0.3, at the time of writing) on *Windows* (it doesn't recognize `.sbtopts` in the project's root directory). All versions now support the `.jvmopts` file.

You can track the status of this issue on [*sbt-launcher-package*'s _GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/issues/92).

**UPDATE**: This [issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/4919#issuecomment-544049693) was fixed in Oct. 2019. Thanks to @conny for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the [sbt-launcher-package](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package) project (under the [sbt projects umbrella](https://github.com/sbt) that adds some certainty) is the way to follow.

Answer (score -1):

You can change JVM options from your build configuration. As an example:

```
fork in run := true

javaOptions += "-Xmx1G"
```

The *fork* option is important because sbt needs to start a new JVM when you execute the *run* task, otherwise options won't be applied to the currently running one.

This explanation assumes that you are using an sbt-style build; if you are using a Scala-based build (that is what I actually use) you should write it as:

```
lazy val yourProject = Project(id = "some-project-id", base = file("./"),
  settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
    fork in run := true,
    javaOptions += "-Xmx1G"
    // ...
  ))
```

Comment: The OP asked about running the sbt launcher with specific settings not a build itself.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the case as he asks:

    Is there a current mechanism to specify project-specific SBT options that works cross platform?

In the way I present you can even tune the options project-by-project in a multi-project build.

Comment: No, Jacek is correct. My original question was how to configure SBT itself. For some reason (I guess for historical reasons related to Java that Scala & SBT have inherited), the default encoding for Windows text files is `windows-1252`, whereas for other OSs, the default encoding is `UTF-8` - an obvious issue for cross-platform compatibility. (Eg. The _Scalastyle_ SBT plugin can give different results for different encodings.) Furthermore, one project requires additional memory resources compared to SBT's default configuration - without them, builds often fail with memory errors.