# Project-specific SBT JVM options: in jenkins

Tags: scala, jenkins, sbt, jenkins-plugins

I'm well aware to the [very similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022362/project-specific-sbt-jvm-options) about project specific JVM options in SBT. and it was most helpfull. I used @gourlaysama solution (from the comments) and used `-J-XsomeOption` syntax in the `.sbtopts` file. And locally, it works great! but I use jenkins with sbt plugin, which seems to ignore the `.sbtopts` file completely! so, is there any way to get jenkins to execute sbt with custom options for each sbt project?

configuring SBT globally would be a terrible idea, since jenkins runs many jobs, and I would'nt want those configurations to take place in any other project.

#### the project structure:

```
my-project/
|-- module1/
|   |-- src/
|   `-- build.sbt
|-- module2/
|   |-- src/
|   `-- build.sbt
...
|
|--- integration-test-module/
|    |-- src/
|    `-- build.sbt
|-- project/
|   |-- build.properties
|   |-- Build.scala
|   `-- plugins.sbt
|-- build.sbt
`-- .sbtopts
```

Comment: Since the setting(s) is part of the build, why don't you include it in the build definition itself? What's the use case? Why would you want to have an external configuration for something that's part of the build?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski it is part of the build. i'm talking about the `myProject/.sbtopts` file. not the global under `~/.sbt/0.13/` or the one under `/path/to/sbt-0.13.2/conf/`. the build is heavy, and i keep getting those annoying `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` errors (which is why i wanted to controll the sbt launcher jvm args).

Comment: Thanks for the update. *"the build is heavy"* - wouldn't that be a sign to split the build to submodules?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski it's a multi-project build. with 12 submodules already... that's not the problem. the `OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` error accures mainly on the integration tests phase, but sometimes, it accurs on other phases of the build. iv'e creted a command alias named `fullTest` which runs each module unit tests, and finally (if all unit tests pass) runs the integration tests.

Comment: IIRC it's possible to give SBT additional parameters from the project configuration. Have you tried that ? May we have more info about the project structure ?

Comment: @Agemen iv'e edited and added the project structure. it's pretty standard. the `.sbtopts` file **is** the configuration for sbt in this project.

Comment: Do you use the same OS both on your PC and server ? Is SBT launched the same on both ?

Comment: yes, and no. locally i use the sbt bash script to launch. jenkins uses something else I guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.sbtopts` file support is a feature of the sbt launch script (bash), not of sbt itself, but the Jenkins plugin calls the sbt launcher jar directly, hence your problem.

Your only options is to manually add your JVM/SBT options in the Jenkins build configuration, under the "Build using sbt" section, see the [sbt plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/sbt+plugin).

<strike>A more long-term option would be to add support for reading `.sbtopts` to the Jenkins plugin.</strike>

**Edit**: I [just added](https://github.com/jenkinsci/sbt-plugin/pull/12) support for `.sbtopts` to the sbt jenkins plugin. It should be in the next (1.5) version.

Comment: this is exactly what Iv'e done meanwhile. it's not ideal to sync it manually, but I guess it's not so bad either. it shouldn't change that often...

Comment: @giladhoch the latest snapshot of the plugin now supports `.sbtopts`, see edit. Until a new version is released, you can always install the `.hpi` manually (downloadable from the https://jenkins.ci.cloudbees.com/job/plugins/job/sbt-plugin/org.jenkins-ci.plugins$sbt/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/org.jenkins-ci.plugins/sbt/1.5-SNAPSHOT/) into `JENKINS_HOME/plugins/`.

Comment: Do not include comments in the .sbtopts file (they become command line args instead of ignored)